# list comprehensions when data are in multiple lists

Tags: python, list, indexing, list-comprehension

Can list comprehensions be used instead of the following loop?

```
a = [1,3,4,7,8,10]
b = [1,1,0,0,0,1]
c=[]

for ii in range(len(b)):
    if b[ii] == 1:
        c.append(a[ii])
```

Comment: It would be a good idea to add a language tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = [1,3,4,7,8,10]
b = [1,1,0,0,0,1]

print([a[ii] for ii in range(len(b)) if b[ii] == 1])
```